# Get the 2 most significant bits

Tags: c#

How can I get the 2 most significant bits of a byte in C#.

I have something like this (value >> 6) & 7 , but I'm unsure if this is correct.

**01**011100 just wanting to return the part in bold.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: what I'm using is returning the correct value. Just wanting to confirm I'm doing it right.

Comment: Actually, you are overdoing it - the `& 7` is unnecessary (and if it wasn't it should really be `& 3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two bits, then you need to `and` by 3 (binary `11`), not by 7 (binary `111`).
So if `value` is a `byte`, something like:

```
byte twobits = (byte)((value >> 6) & 3);
```

Howevers, as the comments stated, this is redundant. It would suffice by right shifting by 6 (since the other bits would be 0 already).

Just for fun, if you want to have the two most significant bits of any data type, you could have:

```
byte twobits = (byte)(value >> (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(value)*8-2));
```

Just as a warning, `Marshal.SizeOf` gives the byte size of the variable type after marshalling, but it "usually" works.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to have the two most significant bits of a byte in another byte, as the least significant bits, with the other bits set to zero.

In that case, you can just return `myByte >> 6` as it will fill the rest of the bits with zeroes (in C# at least). The `& 7` operation seems redundant, the layout of 7 is `00000111`. This means you ensure that the 5 left most bits in the resulting byte are set to zero... You might have intended to ensure the 6 left most bits are zero, in that case it should be `3`.

If you want to return only the left most two bits and keep them in place, then you should return `myByte & 0b11000000`.

Comment: Is 0b11000000 meant to be 0x11000000?

Comment: @Jesse That's an entirely different number (base 16 instead of base 2).

Comment: @Jesse Binary literals will be in C# in the next version, this is not valid syntax yet. Use `192` for base 10 or `0xC0` for hex.